# Discord bot creating and deleting temporary channel

Tags: c#, .net, bots, discord.net

I wanna create the possibility to create the voice channel while the user connects to a specific voice channel and if the owner is left, but another user in the channel, we don't delete the channel, but if the channel is empty then delete it. I have the following code:

```cs
private async Task OnUserVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser socketUser,
    SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, 
    SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
{
    var createTempChannelId = 778596195836100639ul;
    if (socketUser is SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser)
    {
        var server = socketGuildUser.Guild;

        var categoryId = server.CategoryChannels.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Name.Equals("Голосовые каналы"))?.Id;

        bool userWannaCreateTempChannel = socketGuildUser.VoiceState?.VoiceChannel.Id == createTempChannelId;
        if (userWannaCreateTempChannel)
        {
            var voiceChannel = await server.CreateVoiceChannelAsync(socketGuildUser.Username, prop => prop.CategoryId = categoryId);
            _voiceChannels.TryAdd(socketGuildUser.Username, voiceChannel);
            await GetUserVoiceChannelPermissions(voiceChannel, socketGuildUser);
            await socketGuildUser.ModifyAsync(x =>
            {
                x.Channel = Optional.Create(voiceChannel as IVoiceChannel);
            });
        }

        var usersVoiceChannel = (socketGuildUser as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel;
        
        //TODO: fix delete channel when all users leave the channel
        if (usersVoiceChannel == null && socketGuildUser.VoiceChannel.Users.Any())
        {
            await oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is when 2 users are connected and 1 of them is leaves channel is deleting, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Its quite complicated to understand: Which channel should be empty and deleted: oldSocketVoiceState.VoiceChannel or socketGuildUser.VoiceChannel?

Comment: Should be `!socketGuildUser.VoiceChannel.Users.Any()` as you don't want any users in the channel.